# Why can't copy a file from pod to my local

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

I know this question asked before and I checked them but still fails.

Pod name : postgresl-7c8b9-qs67z

File in the pod : /home/backup/db

So I want to try to copy "db" file to my local and I tried to commands below, but all of them giving the same error.

```
 kubectl cp default/postgresl-7c8b9-qs67z:/home/backup/db C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\mydb1.dmp

 kubectl cp default/postgresl-7c8b9-qs67z:/home/backup/ C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\

 kubectl cp postgresl-7c8b9-qs67z:/home/backup/db C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\mydb1.dmp
```

And the error is :

```
error: one of src or dest must be a local file specification
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Currently there seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77310#issuecomment-600571650) in kubectl where `C:` is treaten as the pod name.

Just use a relative path for your local file. E.g:

```
kubectl cp default/postgresl-7c8b9-qs67z:/home/backup/db ./Desktop/mydb1.dmp
```

**additional hint:**

If you receive a `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names`, check if the file was downloaded anyhow.

Comment: Now it's giving "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" error. My local machine is Windows by the way.

Comment: Besides the error message: is the file downloaded?

Comment: Ah, weirdly it's downloaded! Thanks!

Comment: Kept getting hit by `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names` for an hour before realizing that the file has been copied already.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I have

- a namespace called **test**
- a pod called **pod-aabbcc**
- a folder inside pod: **/myfolder/files/pdf/**  it has several files
- my environment run in c:\users\naldo
- I will run

  **kubectl cp -n test pod-aabbcc:/myfolder/files/pdf/ ./salidaPDF/**

The console throws the message: *tar: removing leading '/' from member names*, but you can skip that message.

In c:\users\naldo, automatically kubectl create the folfer /salidaPDF/

c:\users\naldo\salidaPDF

and inside are copied all files.